# Multisite Plugin - Access options (wp_options) on child sites

Tags: plugins, multisite, options

Is there a way I can access the `wp_options` table of all the child sites? I want to create a multisite plugin that can be setup at the network level and will populate the child site plugins with defaults that can then be overwritten by the each individual site. I'm aware that I could read/write from `wp_sitemeta` this way, but in my instance, it would make sense if I could access the other "local" tables. I could probably write a custom query using the WP query function, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `get_blog_option()`. It does not use `switch_to_blog()`, and so introduces much less overhead. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_option

Comment: Is there a function for writing options, too? And is there a function for retrieving all ID's for all sites?

Comment: `update_blog_option()`. I don't think there's a WP function for getting all site ids. Try: `global $wpdb;  $blog_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT blog_id FROM $wpdb->blogs" ) );`

Answer (score 0):

Try [`switch_to_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) and [`restore_current_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog).

Both functions are quite expensive, you may wish to implement only small parts of their functionality, like changing the prefix of `$wpdb`.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/ms-blogs.php